# Firestore snapshotChanges DocumentChangeType "removed" never sent

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire

I'm querying a Firestore collection using a where clause and am subscribed on snapshotChanges. According to the documentation I should get an event for each elements that are added, modified and removed.

I get the added and modified documents fine but I never get the removed ones.

Here's an example of my code:

```
this.db
      .collection<Test>('test', ref => ref.where('someid', '==', someid))
      .snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(async snapshot => {
        for (const element of snapshot) {
          switch (element.type) {
            case 'added':
              // Works fine
              break;
            case 'modified':
              // Works fine
              break;
            case 'removed':
              // Never triggered
              break;
          }
        }
      });
```

I'm assuming it's because of the fact i'm using a where. Has anyone encountered this?

**UPDATE: 2020-10-14**

After more testing, it appears to be an issue only with AngularFirestore and not Firestore itself. In the meantime as a workaround I use AngularFirestore.firestore.onSnapshot directly.

**UPDATE: 2020-11-04**
Turns out with AngularFirestore you need to use stateChanges to get the behavior I was looking for. Hope this can help someone.

Comment: Can you explain when you are expecting to receive a `removed`?

Comment: When one of the elements that was in the collection is removed. Let's say I have 10 elements on that page that match the where clause and one is deleted from Firestore. I would expect to get a "removed" event to be able to update the list on the page.

Comment: You indeed should. Is that not what happens? It really helps if you can include the exact steps with which we can reproduce the problem in your question. I've responded to `remove` events regularly, so it's likely something specific to how you're triggering or handling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out with AngularFirestore you need to use stateChanges to get the behavior I was looking for.

Here's the documentation that explains the difference between snapshotChanges and stateChanges:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md

Answer (score 1):

A listener will receive `removed` events for documents that are removed from the query results **while that listener is active**.

So in your case, that means you'll get the event if:

1. The listener is active, subscribed to the query, and.
2. The document is removed from the collection, or
3. The value of `someid` field in he document changes.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I assume that if my listener wasn't active anymore I would not get the modified documents, which works perfectly fine.

Comment: I still have the issue, i'll reply if I ever find what's causing it

Answer (score 0):

This is happen when you deleted the last item of the collection, at this point of time compiler triggered at empty or null block.