# Firestore listener removes a message from pagination when adding a new message in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am trying to do Firestore reactive pagination. I know there are posts, comments, and articles saying that it's not possible but anyways...

**When I add a new message, it kicks off or "removes" the previous message**

Here's the main code. I'm paginating 4 messages at a time

```
async getPaginatedRTLData(queryParams: TQueryParams, onChange: Function){
  let collectionReference = collection(firestore, queryParams.pathToDataInCollection);
  let collectionReferenceQuery = this.modifyQueryByOperations(collectionReference, queryParams);

//Turn query into snapshot to track changes 
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(collectionReferenceQuery, (snapshot: QuerySnapshot) => {

  snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change: DocumentChange<DocumentData>) => {
    //Now save data to format later
    let formattedData = this.storeData(change, queryParams)
         
    onChange(formattedData);
  })
})

this.unsubscriptions.push(unsubscribe)
}
```

For completeness this is how Im building my query

```
let queryParams: TQueryParams = {
  limitResultCount: 4,
  uniqueKey: '_id',
  pathToDataInCollection: messagePath,
  orderBy: {
    docField: orderByKey,
    direction: orderBy
  }
}    

  modifyQueryByOperations( 
collectionReference: CollectionReference<DocumentData> = this.collectionReference,
queryParams: TQueryParams) {
//Extract query params
let { orderBy, where: where_param, limitResultCount = PAGINATE} = queryParams;
let queryCall: Query<DocumentData> = collectionReference;

if(where_param) {
  let {searchByField, whereFilterOp, valueToMatch} = where_param;
  //collectionReferenceQuery = collectionReference.where(searchByField, whereFilterOp, valueToMatch)
  queryCall = query(queryCall, where(searchByField, whereFilterOp, valueToMatch) )
}

if(orderBy) {
  let { docField, direction} = orderBy;
  //collectionReferenceQuery = collectionReference.orderBy(docField, direction)
  queryCall = query(queryCall, fs_orderBy(docField, direction) )
}

if(limitResultCount) {
  //collectionReferenceQuery = collectionReference.limit(limitResultCount)
  queryCall = query(queryCall, limit(limitResultCount) );
}

if(this.lastDocInSortedOrder) {
  //collectionReferenceQuery = collectionReference.startAt(this.lastDocInSortedOrder)
  queryCall = query(queryCall, startAt(this.lastDocInSortedOrder) )
}

return queryCall
}
```

[image: Notice the last message here] [image: Notice the old message was removed]

See the last line removed is removed when I add a new message to the collection. Whats worse is it's not consistent.  I debugged this and Firestore is removing the message.

[image: WTF?? Why is it getting deleted]

I almost feel like this is a bug in Firestore's handling of listeners

Comment: Is the document being deleted from the firestore itself or is it still there? It could be possible that the values of the fields that your are searching in your query changed while the listener was still active, this makes the listener think of this document as a removed one, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61366937/12857703). If this is not the case, could you also share your function that sets new documents?

Comment: I think thats whats happening. The result is getting removed from the query but not the backend. Ive actually figured it all out and querying it much better now as I create a class and split the old paginated data from the new realtime incoming data

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments and confirmed by you the problem you are facing is occuring due to the fact that some values of the fields that your are searching in your query changed while the listener was still active and this makes the listener think of this document as a removed one.

This is proven by the fact that the records are not being deleted from Firestore itself, but are just being excluded from the listener.

This can be fixed by creating a better querying structure, separating the old data from new data incoming from the listener, which you mentioned you've already done in the comments as well.